# Build failed for ASP.NET Core 3.1 in Travis CI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, build, travis-ci, travis-ci-api

I cannot build my ASP.NET 1 Core 3.1 application in Travis CI and after several unsuccessfull attempts I think it’s time to figure out with the community what’s the problem.

Build: https://travis-ci.org/github/stanislavstoyanov99/CinemaWorld/jobs/686546731
Build config: https://travis-ci.org/github/stanislavstoyanov99/CinemaWorld/jobs/686546731/config

Here’s my repo in GitHub: https://github.com/stanislavstoyanov99/CinemaWorld

I think the problem is that my travis's configuration file is not in the same folder with the solution file, so I put directory path in travis configuration file, but maybe I have some mistakes.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems that dotnet is not installed in the travis runner

Comment: Could you please post some logs in your question so it can be helpful to other users on StackOverflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your travis yml, you are missing a dependency for the dotnet version you want installed:

```
dotnet: 3.1.202
```

<s>I think 3.1.4 is the latest, but feel free to try different versions</s>

Edit: I mixed up the SDK version with the runtime. To build, you need the runtime version, which as of 13/05/2020 is 3.1.202

Comment: The main problem I think is that the nuget dotnet restore command is not found in linux virtual machine that uses travis.

Comment: yes, because in your yml you have not defined what runtime to use. you defined mono:none, but no dotnet version. Check the docs here: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/csharp/#net-core

Comment: Another error is shown when I added dotnet version 3.1.4. Here's the link: https://travis-ci.org/github/stanislavstoyanov99/CinemaWorld/jobs/686698288)

Comment: my bad, I wrote the version of the runtime, not the SDK. Could you try 3.1.202 instead?

Comment: Now there's another problem with the path to solution file:
https://travis-ci.org/github/stanislavstoyanov99/CinemaWorld/jobs/686729437

Comment: I think you need to read up a bit on the proper configuration needed. Maybe check some links like this one: https://medium.com/@pjbgf/configuring-ci-for-net-core-using-travis-ci-and-xunit-cc0f809df4fb It seems that you are selecting the wrong path, as the travis build engine is resolving paths starting from the root of your repo. With that in mind, it should be src/CinemaWorld.sln

Comment: I tried to make exactly the same travis file and again It says dotnet restore exited with code 1. So I tried again with another type of configuration and again the same error - "MSBUILD : error MSB1003: Specify a project or solution file. The current working directory does not contain a project or solution file.". I think there's a huge problem with this system .. There's is a hope according to the restore of my libraries.
Here is the new link: https://travis-ci.org/github/stanislavstoyanov99/CinemaWorld/jobs/687042530

Comment: Thank you so much for the help with 16 unsuccessfull atempts this configuration has built my project successfully: https://travis-ci.org/github/stanislavstoyanov99/CinemaWorld/jobs/687045281
https://i.postimg.cc/DzKHtPm0/travis.jpg

Comment: yay! Glad I helped eventually. If the answer helped you, would you be so kind and mark my answer as accepted?